# Adding CSS to react/JSX to hide a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am hiding and showing a component based on the state of a checkbox, and I am using a ternary operator to decide whether the component is shown or hidden. However, this component is handling data so it would be better to just hide the component with CSS, because every time the component is re-shown, it creates a new request. Below is the ternary operator:

```
const displayWidget = this.state.checked ? <Widget /> : null;
```

I have looked other examples trying to accomplish the same, some suggesting something like:

```
const divStyle = {
   visibility: 'hidden',
}

const displayWidget = this.state.checked ? <Widget /> : <Widget style= {divStyle} />`
```

Is the second example the right way to go about it and I'm just doing something wrong, or is there another way to go about solving this problem?

Comment: I would use the second way, just because I don't know what `JSX` inserts into the `DOM` when the value of an element is `null`. If you know, go for it.

Comment: Better to do: `DisplayWidget  = <Widget className={this.state.checked? 'show': 'hide'}/>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is you can do either, it is simply based on your requirements.

**Returning null**

```
const displayWidget = this.state.checked ? <Widget /> : null;
```

Doing it this way means that when `this.state.checked` is `true` then your `Widget` component is `mounted`and `componentWillMount`/`componentDidMount` will be called.

However, when `this.state.checked` is `false` the `Widget` component will `unmount` and if you stick a `console.log` in the `componentWillUnmount` function you will see this.

If `this.state.checked` is `true` (again) then your `Widget` component is `mounted` (again) and `componentWillMount`/`componentDidMount` will be called (again).

**Hiding via css**

I would change your code to this:

```
const divStyle = {
   visibility: 'hidden',
}

const displayWidget = <Widget style= {...this.state.checked ? {} : divStyle} />
```

This way means that on initial `render` and `this.state.checked` is `true` then it will `mount` in the same way as the null approach.

However, when `this.state.checked` is `false`, `unmount` is **NOT** called as the component is still `mounted` but is now simply being hidden via `css`.

**A alternative approach to hiding a component but keeping it mounted**

```
<Widget visible={this.state.checked} />
```

And in the `render()` method of your `Widget` component you could do something like:

```
render() {
  if (!this.props.visible) {
    return null;
  }
  return <span>widget content</span>;
}
```

Comment: appreciate it! I am leaning more towards the latter two options, as I am doing it via the first way, and it works, but it is probably not the best way for me to be implementing it. When I tried it via hiding using CSS, I was thrown an unexpected token error on the spread before this.state.checked, looking into it now